# Jquery prevent append to multiply each time I press the button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Hello I make a call of an json array with jquery and each time I press the button it should load the list again instead of multiplying.

```
[{"denumire":"Q Club"},{"denumire":"Carul cu Flori"},{"denumire":"La Rocca"}]
```

and my jquery script

```
<script>
$(".filtru").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr(\'href\');
    $.getJSON(href, function(data) {
                        /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
                        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                                $("#restaurant").append(\'<li id="\' + key + \'">\' + val.denumire + \'</li>\');
                        });
                });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty the DIV before you append to it:

```
function (data) {
    $("#restaurant").empty();
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $("#restaurant").append(\'<li id="\' + key + \'">\' + val.denumire + \'</li>\');
    });
}
```

Comment: pff true, I don't know how I didn't thought about it. i think it's late, thnx alot mate ! :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it it will always append the values to your existing div restaurant.
You should try clearing the values from the div first and then start appending the values to it.
I think you should try

```
<script>
$(".filtru").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var href = $(this).attr(\'href\');
$.getJSON(href, function(data) {
 $("#restaurant").empty(); 
                    /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                            $("#restaurant").append(\'<li id="\' + key + \'">\' + val.denumire +  \'</li>\');
                    });
            });
});
</script>
```

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning :)